# Unable to auto post on a Facebook Page using its PHP SDK

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have read at many places that Facebook made some changes around 2018 that prevent people from posting as a page with PHP. I researched for a while to see if I can still auto post on a Facebook page if I am its Admin.

My sources: [Facebook Graph API v3.1 Access Token Permission Limitations For Developers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52457009/facebook-graph-api-v3-1-access-token-permission-limitations-for-developers) and https://adamboother.com/blog/automatically-posting-to-a-facebook-page-using-the-facebook-sdk-v5-for-php-facebook-api/

I am the only one who will use this auto-post app and I am the admin of the page on which I will be posting these links.

Here is the code I tried:

```
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
    'app_id' => 'app_id',
    'app_secret' => 'app_secret',
    'default_graph_version' => 'v2.2',
]);

$pageAccessToken = "page_access_token";


$linkData = [
    'link' => 'some_link',
    'message' => 'some_message'
];
try {
    $response = $fb->post('/me/feed', $linkData, $pageAccessToken);
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
    echo 'Graph returned an error: '.$e->getMessage();
    exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
    echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: '.$e->getMessage();
    exit;
}
$graphNode = $response->getGraphNode();
```

Running the above code, I get the following error:

> Graph returned an error: (#200) If posting to a group, requires app
>   being installed in the group, and \ either publish_to_groups
>   permission with user token, or both manage_pages \ and publish_pages
>   permission with page token; If posting to a page, \ requires both
>   manage_pages and publish_pages as an admin with \ sufficient
>   administrative permission.

Now, I am an admin of the page. I also have selected `manage_pages` and `publish_pages` in permissions. So, why am I getting this error?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On May 5, 2020, Facebook released six new Page permissions to replace the manage_pages and publish_pages permissions. Taking advantage of curl, you can use php to  create and update a post or comment, reply to a post or comment, and delete a post or comment, on your Facebook Page Feed as the Page.

- Send a POST request to the /{page-id}/feed endpoint:

  curl -i -X POST "https://graph.facebook.com/{page-id}/feed
  ?message=Hello Fans!
  &access_token={page-access-token}"
- On success, your app receives the following response:

  {
  "id": "{page-post-id}" 
  }

source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/publishing/

Answer (score 3):

According to the documentation [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/post/), you can not publish posts by using the `feed` edge anymore. [This](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page-post) documentation discusses editing and deleting the posts, it also says we can not create new posts.

Answer (score 0):

You are most likely not using a Page Token, but a User Token. It still works, but you must use a Page Token to post to a Page.

Comment: I select Page Token from the dropdown but after selecting the required permissions it goes back to User Token.

Comment: you have to select the permissions FIRST, and authorize them. after that, you can select the page token from the dropdown.